# Chain v-model succintly?

Tags: vue.js, coffeescript, v-model

Let below code be Child, it is embedded in its Parent, and has a NestedChild which finally features a `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

Now, the code below won't work. Parent rerenders and updates value prop and thus the result is only the last letter typed.

```
// Child.vue
<script lang='coffee'>
  export default
    props: ['value']
    computed:
      edit:
        get: -> @value
        set: (e) -> @$emit 'input', e
    # ...
</script>

<template lang='pug'>
  div
    NestedChild( v-model='edit' )
    //- ...
</template>
```

Text instead needs to be stored in a proxy var.

```
...

data: -> proxy: ''
computed:
  edit:
    get: -> @proxy = @value
    set: (e) -> @$emit 'input', @proxy = e
...
```

Which works for NestedChild -> Child, or Child -> Parent, but not Nested -> Parent, where Parent is in the end storing it in Vuex, disk etc. The value doesn't get updated in Parent.

Simple way to make it work is to pass a `propName` prop to Child which then directly updates relevant data in Vuex by propName, aka by not using v-model at all. But that

- a) smells real bad for my use case - where Parent reads data (from disk eg.) and determines which Children to display (through `component :is`)
- b) is pointless for NestedChildren which in the end contain `<input>`
- c) overall harder in dev stage

Thus really only solving the problem for Child, but not for Parent -> Child -> NestChild1 -> NestChild2 -> ... -> input

So, how to chain v-model succintly? Thanks.

Comment: So if I understand right, you want the event to 'bubble' upwards through several child components until it reaches some parent?

Comment: Yeah. Apparently I don't have a part of the problem anymore, but I don't know why though. No need to proxy the value... ?? :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no need to proxy the value in a separate data var. The original code snippet from the question should work, and it will bubble up to parent and parent's parent etc.

Here's the code again, only converted to javascript and html instead of coffeescript and pug; otherwise identical to the one in the question.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NestedChild v-model='edit'>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  computed: {
    edit: {
      get: function()  { this.value },
      set: function(e) { this.$emit('input', e) }
    }
  }
    // ...
};
</script>
```

(Decided to leave the question, maybe it'd be of use to someone)

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern using composition API and script setup would follow the following

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h4>Child (leaf) Component</h4>
    <input type="text" v-model="myValue" />
    <p>Value: {{ myValue }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from "vue";
const { modelValue } = defineProps<{ modelValue: string }>();
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

const myValue = computed({
  get() {
    return modelValue;
  },
  set(nextValue: string) {
    emit("update:modelValue", nextValue);
  },
});
</script>
```

Keeping to the pattern above:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Parent Component</h2>
    <input type="text" v-model="parentValue" />
    <child-component v-model="parentValue"></child-component>
    <p>Parent Value: {{ parentValue }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent.vue";

import { computed } from "vue";
const { modelValue } = defineProps<{ modelValue: string }>();
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

const parentValue = computed({
  get() {
    return modelValue;
  },
  set(nextValue: string) {
    emit("update:modelValue", nextValue);
  },
});
</script>
```

For this to work the top most element must provide a value for the v-model

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import ParentComponent from './ParentComponent.vue';
const message = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <parent-component v-model="message" />
</template>
```

The following [Playground link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) shows how it can be chained